# Datatables not correctly shown after jquery show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When I try to show a table  which is hidden

```
<div id="buglist" style="display: none"
        <?php include_once("partials/bugs.php");//here is the datatables table 
</div
```

when I call

```
 $("#buglist").show();
```

The table is correct but is small,doesnt fiil the container, without the display:none ,all is correct

Answer (score 0):

try to use removeAttr

```
$("#buglist").removeAttr("style")
```

Answer (score 0):

show() function should display, i think something else is wrong. Are you running on domready?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of show() :

```
$("#buglist").css("display", "block");
```